# How to bypass red5 demo page on start up?

Tags: red5

At present, I start up red5 in linux command line `./red5.sh` and it runs the script. Then I go to `http://localhost:5080` demos page to set up my camera and audio input and all works fine in testing the stream both on demo page and in swf of my webpage.

Question is, do I need to include some java and/or action script for the swf player to
bypass the red5 demo page so I can directly connect my input and stream in the code of the page? Also so only logged in webpage viewers can connect?

Overall wondering if there is a way of hiding the server stream from anyone not logged in to view it on my site? I understand in webapps folder somewhere there is the hosts list of IP but it would be impossible to know the IP of the viewers as opposed to unwanted viewers or bandwidth stealers.

I am trying to set up a site for poetry readings and make it so readers can record live to my server and then logged in viewers can view from my website. I am trying to figure out whether I must have that red5 page open and if that doesn't pose some kind of risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own way of doing this just by removing and renaming files and folders.

If you go to `usr/local/red5/webapps` here lies all the directories for viewing when you go to default port 5080 so I simply installed the applications I needed and then took everything out of there except those applications I wanted and needed to run. I took out all and placed it in a folder in /var directory named it red5_movedstuff in case I want access to further applications later on.Then I renamed the applications I am using in webapps folder and kept admin folder to access them but I renamed my applications and had to importantly rename also in WEB-INF for each application name change.

Now if someone goes to myip:5080 they get a blank page and by changing names of applications I've hidden my directories beyond that including list of streams.